# how does jquery handle js objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, awesomium

I need some help understanding how jquery works. I am using awesomium ui for my game and I am having problem calling functions of jquery objects from my application. Here is my question.

Suppose I have a code like this

```
<div id="test">
  <span>Hello World</span>
</div>
```

and I am triggering an event

```
$('#test').trigger('click');
```

which does

```
$('#test').on('click',function() { $(this).css('color','red'); }
```

This is more of a javascript question, so I am going to give a little bit background on the application function I am using. Awesomium, has a function

```
awe_webview_call_javascript_function
```

that takes parameters as javascript object, the function name inside the object, and the parameters of the function. So, I am passing parameters as

```
jsobject: "$('#test')"
function: "trigger"
parameters: "click"
```

the program doesn't work and I know the reason is the JS object. So, my question is how does jquery implement their elements as js objects? how can I access it?

EDIT: I found solution to the problem. I created a global function trigger with jquery object being the parameter:

```
function trigger(jobj, e, params) {
    $(jobj).trigger(e,params);
}
```

Thanks,
Gasim

Comment: You can provide your solution as answer.

Answer (score 2):

To access the underlying 'real' DOM object from a jQuery selector, you need to use the [get function](http://api.jquery.com/get/) - I don't know Awesomium but it looks from your code like this is what you need. Don't forget that jQuery selectors can match multiple items so get() returns an array, not a single object.

So the first parameter will be something like this:-

```
jsobject: $('#test').get(0);
```

Comment: +1 Indeed. It's helpful to note that the `jQuery` object wraps any selected elements, and a `jQuery` instance is just about always (the exception being some scalar functions) returned from any of its functions, so that you can chain jQuery calls together in a fluent operation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Awesomium but probably jsobject should be the name of a global variable, not an expression. Your code should look something like this:

```
window.awe_jsobject = $('#test');

jsobject: "awe_jsobject"
```

Comment: Your version didn't work either. I don't know. I am going to research it out a little bit more.